# How to declare custom font variable with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-paper

I am using `react-native` and `react-native-paper` for theme.
I want to declare a custom font variable

https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/guides/fonts

```
const CombinedDefaultTheme = {
  ...
  fontConfig: configureFonts({config: {...fontConfig, ...customFontVariant}}),
};
```

I also have declared this one

```
export const Text = customText<'displaySemiBold'>();
```

But I got an error on `typescript`

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: const fontConfig = {
  fontFamily: 'NotoSans'
};

const theme = {
  ...MD3LightTheme,
  fonts: configureFonts({config: fontConfig}), // please correct this in yours
};